# Override minicar sidebar price renderer

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks, template

How can I override a `sidebar.phtml` from:

> module-weee/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml

I have tried in the following ways:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar" template="Eone_GiftProducts::cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml" />
```

AND

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Eone_GiftProducts::cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

I have tried even with actions tag for setTemplate call but no success

I have tried to remove this block and re add it with my custom template but there is no way to makes him work.

I also tried to makes this change into `checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers` handle but with no success.

I must do it for displaying the original price above the price that was displayed in a cart for gift products, I was able to do it on checkout and checkout/cart pages but not able to do it for minicart component.
If i modify directly sidebar.phtml from module-checkout it works like a charm but I cant modify core files.

Answer (score 0):

Could creating a new block and removing the existing one be a valid solution for you?

For example:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar" remove="true" />

<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Item\Price\Renderer" name="eone.checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar" template="Eone_GiftProducts::catalog/product/view/summary.phtml" />
```

If you go down this route be aware you may need to override this function:

```
File: vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php:521

public function getSidebarItemPriceHtml(AbstractItem $item)
    {
        /** @var Renderer $block */
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar');
        $block->setItem($item);
        return $block->toHtml();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this seems not work in any case:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar" remove="true" />
```